# Are all the DIP-16 packages the same for PCB library design?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, packages

I am designing PCB library for a component whose Package is DIP-16. I have already footprint of this Package in other components. Can I use them interchangeably in the new component in terms of their size? Are their size the same?
Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: They should be, more or less.

Comment: You need to verify this using the data sheet, don't assume. DIP-16 should be a standard size, but once in a while you get those odd parts that *say* they are one thing, but use something else.

Comment: The most likely variation is the length. Some DIPs packages extend further past the end pins than others.

Comment: @Mattman944 has mentioned epoxy variations (both width and length). Only other thing might be the lead-frame pin width. Some may require a bigger pad through-hole than others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Almost yes but No.

[image][image].

Please check datasheet for each part. There will be slight differences which you will be able to accept or adjust.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I checked. In my case the differences were very slight and acceptable.

Comment: The dimension you highlighted is one of the least critical for the footprint, though. What is much more critical is the width between the leads, not the width of the plastic part. It is true that the there is a small discrepancy in the tolerance on this dimension too, however.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly yes.

The vast majority of 16 pin DIPs have a 0.1 inch lead pitch and a 0.3 inch width (measured from the Center of one row of pins to the centre of the other row)

You do see the occasional special component though, for example I have used some high isolation optocouplers, which came in a package that was like an 8 pin DIL but with a 0.4 inch width rather than the normal 0.3 inch.

Larger packages can be more variable, in particular 28 pin DIPs traditionally had a 0.6 inch width, but nowadays you also see 0.3 inch wide versions.

The body size may vary slightly, but this is unlikely to be a problem unless you are really pushing the density. If you are laying out parts with the pads on a 0.1 inch grid then I would leave at least one grid position free past the end of each chip.